# How to randomly shuffle multiple lists of the same length in the same order

Tags: list-manipulation, random

If I have a list, I know that I can use the `RandomSample` function to randomly shuffle the list.

However, if I have $n$ lists, each with the same number of elements, is there a way to randomly shuffle the first list and then make the shuffles of the remaining lists be the same rearrangement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your lists (let's call them `list1` and `list2` each have 100 items, then:

```
order = RandomSample[Range[100]];

list1[[order]] 
list2[[order]]
```

(see the documentation for [Part](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html))

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. I do not think you need curly brackets around order though since it is list already.

Comment: Good point @Gabi23—I just typed this blindly.  Modified above.